# Add Range header support IIS 10

Tags: video, safari, iis-10

I have built a web server for loading video (.mp4) in IIS.
Other devices/browsers include mobile work fine except for iOS(safari, chrome on safari...). I searched everywhere I can and know that iOS(safari, chrome on safari...) need range header to play video (.mp4) file.
How can I add range header in IIS to make iOS(safari, chrome on safari...)  can play video (.mp4) file?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Video not work in safari has nothing to do with iis, this is caused by byte-range requests.

Byte-range requests are when a client asks a server for only a specific portion of the requested file. The primary purpose of this is to conserve bandwidth usage by only downloading small sections of the file as needed (a video in your case). If you inspect the Safari video request, you may notice a Range header set to bytes=0-1. This is Safari's way of testing if your HTTP servers accept byte ranges before requesting a larger chunk of data.

To fix your server config, take a look at [Apple's recommendations](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/CreatingVideoforSafarioniPhone/CreatingVideoforSafarioniPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006514-SW6).

Comment: Thanks for reply
  
I tested as the doc you give and see that my server are config properly (receive 100 bytes for range 0-99)
But sometimes safari can't load the mp4 file 
Do you think it caused by encoding ?

Comment: when the mp4 file cannot be loaded, check the console for any error or warning messages